# Python Turtle - Pensize and Coordinates

Tags: python, position, size, coordinates, turtle-graphics

I need the coordinates of every point the python turtle changed.
The problem is that the coordinates I get with `turtle.pos()` (and also `xcor()` and `ycor()`) are always the same, regardless of the set pensize.

Example:

```
width = 5
import turtle
turtle.pensize(width)
turtle.fd(100)
print(turtle.pos())
turtle.done()
```

The Position for every pensize is `(100.00,0.00)`

Is there any way to get all used coordinates?

Thank you in advance!

Edit:
I think the question is a little bit confusing so here's a further explanation:
Let's say we have this code:

```
import turtle
turtle.setheading(45)

# Draw Line with pensize = 20
turtle.pensize(20)
turtle.fd(200)

# Change Pensize to 1 and make turtle red
turtle.pensize(1)
turtle.color("red")

# Draw the same line in red with pensize = 1
turtle.bk(200)

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

Now we have a big black line and a thinner red line (see image). With both `turtle.pos()` and `turtle.get_poly()` I get the coordinates of the red line. But I need the coordinates of the thick black line, so every spot the turtle drew (which dependence on the pensize)

[See example Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehpcy.jpg)

Comment: `turtle.get_poly()` is ((0.00,0.00), (141.42,141.42), (0.00,0.00)),  (0.00,0.00) to (141.42,141.42) for balck, (141.42,141.42) to (0.00,0.00) for red. you need to record what index for the black line. Maybe still don't know what your requirements, for your code, what the result you expect ? ((0.00,0.00), (141.42,141.42)) ?

Comment: @JasonYang Yes it's the same result. But I need all coordinates of everything that's black in the picture, not just the red ones.

Comment: That's `(0.00,0.00), (141.42,141.42))` in your sample code. You need do the management by yourself when pencolor changed.

Answer (score 0):

`pensize` won't change the position ot turtle, just pen width only

```py
import turtle

def forward(distance):
    turtle.fd(distance)
    print(turtle.pos())

width = 5
turtle.pensize(width)
print(turtle.pos())

forward(100)
forward(50)
forward(100)

turtle.done()
```

```py
(0.00,0.00)
(100.00,0.00)
(150.00,0.00)
(250.00,0.00)
```

Using `start_poly`, `get_poly`, `end_poly` to record the vertices of a polygon.

```py
import turtle

def forward(distance):
    turtle.fd(distance)

turtle.begin_poly()
width = 5
turtle.pensize(width)
forward(100)
forward(50)
forward(100)
print(turtle.get_poly())
turtle.end_poly()
turtle.done()
```

```py
((0.00,0.00), (100.00,0.00), (150.00,0.00), (250.00,0.00))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. The `get_poly` command gives me the same information as the `turtle.pos` command.  What I need is are the coordinates of every other spot that the turtle "dyed"..

Comment: Not sure what you mean for the turtle "dyed".  `print(turtle.get_poly())` return the result `((0.00,0.00), (100.00,0.00), (150.00,0.00), (250.00,0.00))` which record all positions turtle stop, not same as `turtle.pos()` which just one coordinate (250.00,0.00).

Comment: I think the question was a little bit confusing, so I tried to explain my problem further by editing the original post. Thank you very much!